# Extract string between doublequotes

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this type of string:

```
var request = "http://learning.com/";
```

I wan to extract `http://learning.com/` only, below is the code I use:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(sourcecode, "var request = """"([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\,]*)?""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

At the end I don`t get anything. Not sure where is the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is the fact that you are trying to use quantifiers inside of your character class instead of correctly preceding the class with a quantifier `[\w.]+`. I would simply use a negated class instead of that hideous regex.

```
Dim s as String = "some sourcecode here .... var request = ""http://learning.com/"""
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s, "var request = ""([^""]+)""")
If (m.Success) Then
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
End If
```

<kbd>[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/RmkFWD)</kbd>